# Simple PHP Code; Blank Screen?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm just starting to learn PHP. I have a friend who's fairly good at it, and had him look at my code, and he couldn't see anything wrong with it, and said I should try here.

Basically, I was just playing around and wanted to make a simple "to-do" list.

Here is the code for my index.php file:

```
<html>
<title>
Tasks
</title>
<body>

<?php

echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
<br>
<br>
include("tasks.php"); 
?>

<br>

<br>


</body>
</html>
```

And, finally, my tasks.php file:

```
<ol>

<li> 1. Wow.
<li> 2. Cool.
<li> 4. Oops.

</ol>
```

It seems to me like it should be working, but all I get is a white screen. If I take out the include statement, I get the echo statement fine, so I think it must be something wrong with the include statement. Also, I have made sure that the index.php and tasks.php file are in the same directory.

Thank you all so much for your help.

Comment: How are you executing that file? Are you running it under a server/localhost?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using MAMP and accessing from lcoalhost:8888. Thanks for your interest in helping me!

Comment: as you say yourself, the problem is probably inside the include. Try enabling errors with `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);` and check the error messages.

Comment: you're new, so maybe you don't know: if your question is answeder by someone, you should mark that answer by clicking the tick-mark next to it.

Answer (score 4):

change

```
<?php

echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
<br>
<br>
include("tasks.php"); 
?>
```

to

```
<?php
echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
?>
<br />
<br />
<?php
include("tasks.php"); 
?>
```

PS: you should realy try to write correct html - you havn't closed you li-elements and you havn't written the `br` as empty element (`<br />`, not `<br>`)

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I should have mentioned alternatives I've tried. That was one of them :( I'll try it again right now and let you know!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! As wel as the tip about HTML. I learned HTML about 10 years ago and haven't really touched it since, so I'm surely very sloppy and should correct that.

Comment: Your code worked marvels. It also turned out that at least part of my error was that localhost:8888 wasn't even showing index.php for some reason, I had to specifically access localhost:8888/index.php. Wierd!

Comment: Though is `<br>`  still a valid tag, `<br />` is for xhtml.

Comment: The end tag for `<li>` is optional in [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#edef-LI), but not in XHTML, much as with `<br>`

Comment: -1 for not pointing out that the real problem is the OP doesn't know how to record and find errors!

Answer (score 2):

Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on the top of script, then you will know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You've not included the break line tags 
 correctly inside your PHP:

```
<html>
<title>
Tasks
</title>
<body>

<?php

echo "I have so many tasks to do...<br><br>";

include("tasks.php"); 
?>

<br>

<br>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you have mixed `<br>` tags in php code:

```
<?php
echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
<br> // <-- Wrong
<br> // <-- Wrong
include("tasks.php"); 
?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php
echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
?>
<br />
<br />
<?php
include("tasks.php"); 
?>
```

Or:

```
<?php
echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';
include("tasks.php"); 
?>
```

You have also not written closing tags for `li`:

```
<ol>

<li> 1. Wow.
<li> 2. Cool.
<li> 4. Oops.

</ol>
```

Should be:

```
<ol>
  <li> 1. Wow. </li>
  <li> 2. Cool. </li>
  <li> 4. Oops. </li>
</ol>
```

**Note:** To get error messages/description on your screen rather than blank window, put these two lines on top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: -1 The bit about `<li>` and `<br>` is incorrect, unless the page is XHTML sent as application/xhtml+xml (unlikely, as it breaks IE). If it were, the browser (at least Firefox) would usually show an error page, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors:

1- 
`<br>` cannot be inserted into `<?php ?>` tags. It is an html tag that must be out of the php code or inside a string.
So close the `<?php` with `?>` before `<br>` and re open them before the include as already pointed out.

2- `<li>` tags must be closed with `</li>` but that is not the meaning of the blank page.

The page is blank due to the parse error the php compiler output because of the two "
".
It seems that you have your error_reporting(0) to 0. Please set on the top of your page the following code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

So that you will be able to output error messages and fix them.

Comment: Your second point is only an issue for XHTML sent as `application/xhtml+xml`, which is not normally the case. Not downvoting as your first point is correct.

Comment: Actually it is true that the w3c has specified that the </li> end tag is optional but as far as the xhtml (which is pretty used) says it must be closed, shouldn't we?

Comment: XHTML is parsed as strict XML if and only if `Content-type: application/xhtml+xml`, which very few websites do. HTML parsing (including XHTML with `Content-type: text/html`, which is the default) will render the above without issues. Basically, it's *very* unlikely that unclosed tags would cause errors. If the `</li>` was required, then there might be a rendering issue, but the page would be displayed.

Comment: I said that: "but that is not the meaning of the blank page."

Answer (score 0):

You use `<br>` tags inside of PHP script which isn't permitted. You'll have to change

```
<?php

echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
<br>
<br>
include("tasks.php"); 
?>
```

into

```
<?php

echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
?>

<br>
<br>

<?php
include("tasks.php"); 
?>
```

Eventually you could also put `<br>` tags inside of your `echo`:

```
<?php

echo "I have so many tasks to do...<br /><br />";

include("tasks.php"); 
?>
```

which would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

blank screen probably means You're using production server error-reporting, 
try

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

on first row after the open-php-tag

Comment: php5 is picky when you check for non-initalized variables. It's of course a good thing, but many older php-libraries aren't coded with that in mind, for example, //if ($_GET['action']=='view') will report notice-error if no action supplied in querystring.

Answer (score 0):

To summarise what you have been told:

```
<html>
<title>
Tasks
</title>
<body>
<?php
echo "I have so many tasks to do...";
?>
<br>
<br>
<?php
include("tasks.php"); 
?>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Should be your main and:

```
<ol>

<li> 1. Wow. </li>
<li> 2. Cool. </li>
<li> 4. Oops. </li>

</ol>
```

Should be tasks.php